# How to publish a Xamarin.Forms App on Windows?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, xamarin.forms

I have developed a cross-platform application in Visual Studio 2015, with Xamarin.Forms. My application is ok and works on Visual Studio.

What I want is very basic but I can't find how to do it. I need to give this application to my friend because I want him to test it on Windows, but I do not want to give him Visual Studio. I'd expect to be able to give him a .exe file or something like that.

How can I do that ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jason.

In short, I have to : 
- right click on the project in Visual Studio.
- Select "Store" => "Create App packages..."
- Choose "No" to the first question
- In the build folder, right click the .ps1 file, and select "Run with Power Shell".

Then the application is installed on my computer, and I can run it easily by starting it from the Windows menus.

To give it to my friend for a test, I just have to copy the build folder on his computer.